# What's the best practice to update Redux state in components that needs the same values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have some components that can render together in a page or separately, but they need the same state (order info), which is an object with all the order info. Each component uses the data it needs from this state.

I'm using redux to manage the state, so when I update the state in one component, all other components can read this state change and update as well.

The problem is that this state comes from the API and its initial state is an undefined object:

```
const initialState = {
    orderInfo: undefined,
};
```

This is because it will only have its state when the customer navigates to explore an order. So whenever the customer navigates to `/dashboard/orders/:id/`, the component needs to fetch the data from the API.

What I initially thought was to check if the state is undefined or if it's from a different order id. If so, dispatch the action to fetch from the API:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // check if orderState contains order info and it's the same order
    if (!orderState.orderInfo || orderState.orderInfo._id !== id) {
        dispatch(getOrderInfo(id));
    }
    //eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);
```

This works, but I have to implement this check on every component, because they can render alone. The problem is that when there are more than 1 component in the page, all of them dispatch the action to fetch the data from the API in the same time.

What's the best way to make only one component to dispatch the action?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the top level component that renders at `/dashboard/orders/:id`? That's where you should be making your initial fetch calls for that route.

Comment: One of the ways,

You can maintain a `State` variable which stores the `ApiCallsInProgress`.

When you make the first API call,`increment` this state variable by `1`. And when `response` is received, `decrement` it by `1` or simply in this case put it as `0`.

For any subsequent API call from dispatch action (any component), check whether this `ApiCallsInProgress` is `> 1`. If yes, skip this api call.

Hope this helps

Comment: @lawrence-witt it's just a page which holds components. This page has no state or any logic.

Comment: @RohitKhanna thank you, I'll consider this implementation. But is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways that might be good for you:

1: [Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

- You can have a hook that handles that useEffect, and dispatch logic, and which also consumes the selector of the data in the store. Something like:

```
function useOrder(foo, bar) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const order = useSelector(selectOrder)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (foo) {
      dispatch(bar)
    }
  }, [foo, bar])

 return order
}
```

And then just consume it in your components by:

```
const order = useOrder(foo, bar)
```

2.- Parent container.

- If all components are present at the same time, there must probably be a global container that contains them all. You could just handle there your dispatch logic and pass down the property.
  For passing down props you also got 2 options:

  - Explicit passing by prop (so just pass the prop to each nested component that needs it)
  - Using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

```
const ctx = createContext({...})

<Provider context={ctx}>
 // Your component hierarchy
</Provider>
```

And then inside each of the components use the `useContext` hook.

*Edit: 
In the first hook example, i passed the props directly to the hook, but for your example you might take that props from another selector as well.

Comment: Option 1 is very clever. I was implementing the useEffect one by one, and had a `instances` count inside the action, which would verify if it's greater than 0. If it was, I would return the action without dispatching it, else I would continue to dispatch the action. It's working fine. Option 2 is good also, but I wouldn't like to have it's logic in parent components